# how to cancel TimerTask by number of times

Tags: android

I want to indicate simple animation on appWidget.

the animation is made from 2 bitmap.

```
Resources r = getResources();
         Bitmap ani[] = {BitmapFactory.decodeResource(r, R.drawable.anime1),BitmapFactory.decodeResource(r, R.drawable.anime2)};
```

there is counter

```
int counter = 0;
```

and here is run method in TimerTask.

```
    @Override
            public void run() {
                AppWidgetManager awm = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), sample.class);
                RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.mainlayout);
                rv.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.material, ani[counter]);
                awm.updateAppWidget(cn, rv);
counter++;

            }
```

when i execute `timer.schedule` with them,
how can i stop this counter==2?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you require. I assume you need to cancel if the counter reaches 2.

```
    int count=0;
    _t = new Timer();
    _tv.setText(""); 
    _t.scheduleAtFixedRate( new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                _count++;

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() //run on ui thread
                 {
                  public void run() 
                  { 

                      _tv.setText(""+_count);
                      if(_count==2)
                      {
                          _t.cancel();
                      }
                 }
                 });
            }
        }, 1000, 1000 );
```

You can also use handler. Using a timer task will create a new thread. Updating ui should be done on the UI Thread. Better to use a handler.

Answer (score 2):

You should stop the timer inside the run of timertask after checking the condition.

```
    TimerTask timerTask=new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(counter==2){
        timer.cancel();
        }
    }
};
```

The timer should be like this.

```
Timer timer=new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, when, period);
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(counter == 2)
{
    timer.cancel();
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: sorry, i can't find comment button below the question

Comment: You will need 50 reps to comment on any post, I think that's why you are not able to see it.

Answer (score 0):

don't use TimerTask, use Handler instead for such task